# How to remove underline from <sub> in <u> tag?

Tags: html, css

How can I remove the underline in a subscript text enclosed in the `<u>` tag with CSS?

This doesn't work.

```css
u sub {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<u>The text should be underlined,<sub>but not the subscript</sub></u>
```

Comment: You would be better off changing the markup so the sub in not in the `u`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set `sub` to `display: inline-block;`

```css
u sub {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<u>The text should be underlined,<sub>but not the subscript</sub></u>
```

Comment: Nice to learn this.

Comment: I don't know why, nor how, but that worked. Thank you! :-)